# How to compare effects of predictors between GAMs?

Tags: effect-size, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have two models, which share some predictors. I'd like to compare the magnitude of their effects on the respective response variable.

Here's an example based on data and code taken from [here](https://github.com/eric-pedersen/mgcv-esa-workshop/blob/master/example-forest-health.Rmd).

Data:

```
library(mgcv)

forest <- read.table(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eric-pedersen/mgcv-esa-workshop/master/data/forest-health/beech.raw"),
                     header = TRUE)

forest <- transform(forest, id = factor(formatC(id, width = 2, flag = "0")))

## Aggregate defoliation & convert categorical vars to factors
levs <- c("low","med","high")
forest <- transform(forest,
                    aggDefol = as.numeric(cut(defol, breaks = c(-1,10,45,101),
                                              labels = levs)),
                    watermoisture = factor(watermoisture),
                    alkali = factor(alkali),
                    humus = cut(humus, breaks = c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5),
                                labels = 1:4),
                    type = factor(type),
                    fert = factor(fert))
forest <- droplevels(na.omit(forest))
forest$ph <- as.numeric(forest$ph)

ctrl <- gam.control(nthreads = 3)
```

Models:

```
forest.m1 <- gam(aggDefol ~ s(age) + ph + watermoisture,
                     data = forest, 
                     family = ocat(R = 3), 
                     method = "REML",
                     control = ctrl)

forest.m2 <- gam(canopyd ~ s(age) + ph + watermoisture + aggDefol,
                     data = forest, 
                     method = "REML",
                     control = ctrl)
```

How can I determine if e. g. the effect of `s(age)` and `watermoisture` is stronger on `aggDefol` than `canopyd`?

Comment: Have we normalised the two response variables `aggDefol` and `canopyd` to be on a similar scale? Also, `ph` is used as a categorical variable in this code and I am doubtful that this is intentional or correct. Finally, using `defol` in its "numeric state" might be more straightforward for immediate comparisons so the two models has response variables of the same family.

Comment: Actually looking at this for a moment again, `aggDefol` is a response variable in  `m1` but an explanatory variable in `m2`. That makes the effect of `s(age)` and `watermoisture` in `m2` compounded by any information we have in `m1` by `aggDefol`.  It would be more straightforward to exclude `aggDefol` from `m2`.

Comment: @usεr11852 They are not normalised, but could be e. g. z-standardised I guess. And ph should be a continuous variable. The different families is part of the "problem" that I want to solve and in my original data the response variables cannot be modified unfortunately. The response variable of m1 being a predictor in m2 is another part of the problem and I am particularly looking at the effect of this predictor in m2, so it cannot be excluded. That's why I am clueless ;)

Comment: Do you care about an answer in general or is it about this data speciffically. I'm asking because `m2` is very badly mispecified. 0 to 100 in 10 steps and 50% is 90 or 100. That will never have normal residuals and should probably be another ordinal category model. Maybe with some aggregation for the lower values.

Comment: "*And ph should be a continuous variable.*" << Maybe you change the code to reflect that. :) Also, after reading your comments: Shouldn't your question be: "*How can I determine if e. g. the effect of `s(age)` and `watermoisture` is stronger on `aggDefol` than on `canopyd` when given `defol`/`aggDefol` information?*" (Also, you can always use `defol` in a spline and avoid bucketing it but that's a minor point here.)

Comment: I edited the code! And yes, that is the question, sort of implied by the model set-ups?

Comment: Hmm... I will collate my comments into an answer during the weekend but as mentioned, given the lack of using a common scale as well as the reuse of one of the variables as an explanatory feature, the overall situation is quite murky.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It is slightly more informal than I would like but I tried to keep it somewhat concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing whether the effect of variable $x_1$ is stronger on a response variable $y_1$ than another $y_2$ is reasonably straightforward if certain conditions are met such that the question is well-defined.

Generally speaking, the coefficient $\beta_1$ gives us an idea about the estimated average change in response per unit of change of $x_1$. Now, assuming $y_1$ and $y_2$ are on the same scale, we are comparing changes to $y_1$ apples to $y_2$ apples, so we are good.

Thus the first issue here is that $y_1$ is an ordinal categorical variable and  $y_2$ is a Gaussian; on face value, this is "not great" but not all is lost. *Luckily*, we have an identity link for our ordinal model `m_1` meaning that our linear predictor is "just" a latent variable that is then segmented based on the estimated transition thresholds.
That means that we can squint our eyes and say that the beta's from `m_1` and `m_2` refer to the same scale, just for `m_1` the scale is the latent scale and in `m_2`  the response scale. So the first thing to do here is to rescale `aggDefol` and `canopyd` to have the same scale. This is *is* going to be a quirky thing to do as I strongly suspect that changing `canopyd` to be in $[1,3]$ is likely necessary because R encodes order categorical variables as integers. But theoretically can be done. Let me note if we simply use `defol` and `canopyd` directly as numeric values normalised to be $N(0,1)$, our task would be greatly simplified and probably more coherent. We are using splines for `age` and `ph` after all so if there are strong non-linearities due to them we should still be able to account for them.

The second issue is that `aggDefol` is a response variable in model `m_1` but one of the explanatory variables in `m2`. That makes the effect of `age` and `watermoisture` in `m_2` compounded by any information we have in `m_1` by `aggDefol`. Simply put, we  *should't do it* as it is complicated and rife with possible bias due to confounding and/or mediating effects. But let's say we throw caution to the wind. We could use *the estimated response*  of `defol` from `m_1` as a feature in `m_2`, not the raw values. As such, our comparison on "*whether the effect of `age` on  `defol` is greater than the one on `canopyd`*" becomes the comparison of $\beta_{\text{age}}^{m_1}$ against the combined effect of `age` in `canopyd` which will be $\beta_{\text{age}}^{m_2} + \beta_{\text{age}}^{m_1}$. It is very messy, but assuming that `canopyd`  and `defol` are on the same scale it "works". It will be also a mess to do when using a spline basis so I would strongly suggest using a polynomial basis so it is clear what comparisons are done.

To recap, I strong suggest reformulating the question. First of all, use similar response scales so it is *obvious* what they represent. Second, avoid using the same variable $x$  as a response variable and as an explanatory variable; if we cannot help it,  we can use the predicted variable from the one model instead of the raw variables because in that way we effectively allow information from variable $x$ to come in the second model only through the other variables (as the response from `m_1` will be simply the linear combination of the explanatory variables of it).

OK and some code:

```
forest$defol_norm = scale(forest$defol)
forest$canopyd_norm = scale(forest$canopyd)
forest.m1 <- gam(defol_norm ~ poly(age,2) + s(ph) + watermoisture,
                 data = forest, method = "REML")
forest$pred_defol = predict(forest.m1)
forest.m2 <- gam(canopyd_norm ~  poly(age,2)  + s(ph) + watermoisture + pred_defol,
                 data = forest, method = "REML")
# Get the effects expected by "watermoisture2", perform similar analysis for other vars
abs(forest.m1 |> coefficients()|> getElement("watermoisture2"))
abs(forest.m2 |> coefficients()|> getElement("watermoisture2") + 
    forest.m1 |> coefficients()|> getElement("watermoisture2"))
```

suggesting that both `age` and `watermoisture` have a much more pronounced effect on (normalised) `canopyd` rather than on (normalised) `defol`. Also, note that this methodology only focused on $\beta$'s. As all $p$-values suggested reasonable levels of statistical significance across all the explanatory variables examined, there is the working assumption that "all variables are equally important but have different effect sizes".

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your effort! I very much appreciate your thoughts and ideas on how to tackle this indeed very tricky question. I will use it as a very useful starting point to hopefully come to an overall reasonable solution.